# Counting opened Images in shell scraping

Tags: image, shell, count

how do count photos that have been opened?
using shell Scepting
I have been using the command that counters a number of jpg images

'find *.jpg | wc -l'

but I need to find out how many times has been opened

Comment: Opened by what, when, how?

Comment: open by terminal

Comment: Terminal doesn't open images

Comment: I mean a command that cont in particular path to find how many times has been opened